# Throwing exceptions through components, good practice?

Tags: java, java-8

When a sub method throws an exception, would encapsulation in a dedicated "package" exception be considered good pratice ?

```
    public String doStuff() throws UtilsException {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException("test");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new UtilsException("something occured", e);
        }
    }

    //use this exception for all classes of this package / component
    public class UtilsException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public UtilsException() {
            super();
        }

        public UtilsException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }

        public UtilsException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

        public UtilsException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);
        }

    }
```

Could `Optional.empty()` be an alternative to avoid throwing/catching of a complex app?

```
    public Optional<String> doStuff() throws UtilsException {
        try {
            return Optional.of("ok");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            LOG.error("Something append... {}", e.getMessage());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping a low-level exception into a high-level exception might be a good practice in some setups, but it not if you are talking about a `NullPointerException`. You should not even catch a `NullPointerException`. It has the same meaning in all levels of you application. An `Optional` encapsulates a potentially absent value, not a report that a `NullPointerException` has happened. Avoid the `NullPointerException` in the first place. You can do that by using an `Optional`.

Comment: The NullPointerException was just to explain my setup. Wrapping seems interesting to follow the source of the exception.

Comment: Then you picked a really bad example. Consider, a `ClassNotFoundException` encapsulating an `IOException` that occurred while loading the class bytes. A special case are API layers not allowing checked exceptions, e.g. consider a `Collection` view to a database. There, failures of the underlying storage system have to be wrapped, e.g. in `IllegalStateException`s or `NoSuchElementException`s. I think, these make better examples.

Comment: When a deep method throws something, is it also a bad pratice to throw exceptions throw the call stack, in order to stop the execution of the first caller ?

Comment: See http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075476/core-java/exceptional-practices--part-1.html?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should **never** catch a NullPointerException (or runtime exceptions in general) an return someting else like you are doing. 
Ok, maybe there are a very few cases where you need to do that (like a buggy third party api).

Exceptions like those (NullPointer, ClassCast, IllegalArgument, ect) happen when your program has a bug and you should let 
them bubble up and handle them in some high order component of your program.

That being said, (and there comes the infamous phrase) it depends...

Exceptions are "responsible" for informing errors,thus they need to be informative for the caller will use them to decide what to do. Consider the following:

```
public void readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    // read file content
    return content;
}


try {
    return readFile("foo.txt");
} catch(FileNotFound e) {
    // For this specific scenario not finding the file is not a problem       
    return "";
} catch(IOException e) {
    // This we are not expecting to happen, if the file exists we should be 
    // able to read it, otherwise we should inform the user.
    log.error(e);
    display("We had a problem reading the file, Check the file permissions and try again");
}
```

As you can see in the example above, you won't want to wrap the IOException in another exception in this case
because you will remove the client's ability to decide what to do when an error happened.

*Also, note that the IOException is a form of "wrap" since exceptions are objects too you can use inheritance
to generalize what kind of errors your method throws and then throw more specific errors so the caller can 
decide what to do.*

## When to wrap.

There are cases when wrapping exceptions is a good practice and is the way to go.
For example, if you are creating a lib whose main functionality is to get weather information.

For the first version you kept it simple and used a third party api to get the values for the day.
The main method of your api looks like this.

```
public Weather getWeather(Date day) throws HTTPException {
    return weather.get(day);
}
```

Your api is doing pretty well but you noticed you're doing too much requests to the weather api and
you will have to start paying for it very soon. You then decided to cache the results in a database table
so you can reduce the amount of requests.

```
public Weather getWeather(Date day) throws HTTPException, SQLException {
    Weather w = getFromCache(day);
    if (w != null) {
        return w;
    } else {
        return getAndCache(day);
    }
}
```

Now you have a problem, you can't add this new exception to the throws statement because you will most certainly break
your api's users code.

And if you think about it, your api's users are no interested if you had problems getting the data from the wheter api or
from your cache, they just want to be informed of errors. This is a very good case to wrap those exceptions in 
a more generic one, like `WeatherFetchException`.

*As you can see, it really depends...*

The rule of thumb to me is, **keep your exceptions meaningful** and if you want to wrap them, do only when
it makes sense and when it doesn't remove the caller's ability to handle errors.

Wrapping exceptions just for the sake of it is most definitely not a good practice.